# Central Authentication Server : How to configure?

Tags: docker, single-sign-on, cas

I am developing a CAS middleware for my software. I want to identify my users based on a third party CAS Server.

To test my development, I deployed a cas server using docker. I'm a bit blocked to proceed forward.

I can connect to it with the default credentials `casuser/Mellon` but I dont'know how to do anything else. I need to declare my software as a service in order to use SSO. Creating more users would be a plus.

PS: I'm a noob at both CAS ans Docker.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have done the basic CAS configuration and you are able confirm that by logging in using the default credentials.

To do beyond default credentials, you need to expand your configuration. CAS is really good in providing multiple options to do this. Please refer to the link below,

https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#accept-users-authentication